# Quickest way to extract leading text using Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have something like `$string = ABC_RPM_LOL`   and  `GELO_FRE_OPN`
I would like to extract `ABC` and `GELO`. (The word before 1st underscore).

What is the **quickest** way to achieve this using Perl?

Comment: Thanks alot guys.. all these answers are indeed insightful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regex you could use is:

```
$string =~ /^([A-Z]+)_/;
$value = $1;
```

This assumes that your words are made up of only upper-case letters. If they're mixed case, throw an `i` on the end of the regex: `/^([A-Z]+)_/i`.

**Edit:** Since you asked for the quickest way, here's a benchmark comparing my regex and [Lazarus's `split`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8537744/424509):

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark qw/ :all /;

my $string = "ABC_RPM_LOL";
my $value;

my $count = 10_000_000;
cmpthese( $count, {
    'regex' => sub { $string =~ /^([A-Z]+)_/; $value = $1; },
        'split' => sub { ($value) = split /_/, $string; }
});
```

The results:

```
           Rate regex split
regex 1869159/s    --  -29%
split 2624672/s   40%    --
```

So `split` is a heck of a lot quicker.

**Edit the second**: I added three of the other answers here:

```
'split2' => sub { $value = (split('_',$string))[0]; },
'split3' => sub { ($value) = split /_/, $string, 2; },
'substr' => sub { $value = substr $string, 0, index $string, '_'; },
```

And the new results:

```
            Rate  regex split2 split3  split substr
regex  1848429/s     --    -8%   -27%   -28%   -63%
split2 2008032/s     9%     --   -21%   -22%   -60%
split3 2538071/s    37%    26%     --    -1%   -50%
split  2570694/s    39%    28%     1%     --   -49%
substr 5050505/s   173%   152%    99%    96%     --
```

[tadmc's `substr` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8538506/424509) is the fastest by a huge margin.

Comment: You do realize that `split` and `split3` are identical right? `perl -MO=Deparse -e'($value) = split /_/, $string;'` ( Ok there may be a very slight compilation penalty )

Comment: Great answer but by your own admission @tacmc actually delivered the correct one, +1 never the less. Good work!

Comment: @Lazarus: Yeah, I would have given tadmc the checkmark for getting the right answer. :)

Comment: @CanSpice: Ah well, it was good work and a cracking bit of analysis so I would have wanted to +1 more than once anyway. I learnt something, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

My experience tells me that Ron is new to programming.

"Quickest" is very seldom corresponds with "best"...

But, if we really want quickest, I'd start with substr/index:

```
my $word1 = substr $_, 0, index $_, '_';
```

If I thought that "Quickest" was not a simple case of premature optimiztion, then I would benchmark several different ways to answer that question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the string into more than two.

When `split` is specified the optional third parameter, it will use it to limit the number of resultant strings (and subsequently work done):

```
my ( $word ) = split /_/, $str, 2;
```

Comment: Actually `my ( $word ) = split /_/, $str;` is transformed into `my ( $word ) = split /_/, $str, 2;` at compile time. `perl -MO=Deparse -e'my ( $word ) = split /_/, $str'` So you really don't need to specify the limit.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a Regex for this, the humble `split` function is your friend.

```
$extract = (split(/_/, $string))[0];
```

Comment: `($extract) = split /_/, $string;`

Comment: `($extract) = split /_/, $string, 2;` should be a few percent faster, and maybe much more if you have lots of underscores in the string.

Comment: Actually @DavidBrigada, `($extract) = split /_/, $string;` is transformed into `($extract) = split /_/, $string, 2;` at compile time. `perl -MO=Deparse -e'($extract) = split /_/, $string'`

Answer (score 1):

you need something like

```
$abc = split('_', $string)[0] # when string = ABC_RPM_LOL
$gelo = split('_', $string)[0] # when string = GELO_FRE_OPN
```

Comment: `($abc) = split /_/, $string;` transforms into `($abc) = split /_/, $string, 2;` which stops it from having to do more work than it really needs to.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string="ABC_RPM_LOL and GELO_FRE_OPN";
my @list = ( $string =~ m{(?:\b|\s)(\w+?)_}g );
print "@list\n";
```